# Proper way to convert to an int

Tags: python, pandas

What would be the proper way to do the following:

```
df['file_size'] = np.where(df['file_size'], int(df['file_size']), None)
```

Currently the error I get is:

> TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>

And when trying to do it directly:

```
df['file_size'] = df['file_size'].astype(int)
```

> ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer

Comment: If we can convert non integer values to 0 then I think we can use
**df['file_size'] = df['file_size'].fillna(0).astype(int)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`integer_na`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/integer_na.html) because by default at least one missing value convert integers to floats (because `NaN` is `float`), so need special type `Int64` for resolve this problem:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'file_size':[5,4,np.nan,None]})

df['file_size'] = df['file_size'].astype("Int64")
print (df)
   file_size
0          5
1          4
2       <NA>
3       <NA>
```

Comment: yes that works thank you. Could you please briefly explain the difference between using `int` and `"Int64"` ?

Comment: int will try to use a numpy dtype ("int64" or lower. Note the lowercase i in "int64" denotes numpy's dtype). numpy does not have or support an integer NA. Integer NA (`pd.NA`) is unique to `pandas` and arrays containing this value have an "Int64" dtype (note the capital i). see [pandas integer na](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html) for more information.